# Fixing incorrect contour lines occurring around 0 longitude

Tags: python-3.x

I'm fairly new to plotting contour lines. When plotting ice data that crosses over longitude zero in the Arctic, the contour lines create horizontal lines that span the x axis. Ideally I'd merge the lines so they created one solid contour, but failing that just removing the horizontal lines would be enough.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTnPC.jpg (I'm new and not allowed to post pictures yet, but this shows the problem clearly)

```
 from netCDF4 import Dataset, MFDataset, num2date
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.util import add_cyclic_point
import pandas as pd
from netCDF4 import Dataset as NetCDFFile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nc = NetCDFFile('LongitudeLatitudeGrid-n3125-Svalbard-  from20190129.hdf')
lats = nc.variables['Latitudes'][:]
lons = nc.variables['Longitudes'][:]
nc17 = NetCDFFile('asi-AMSR2-n3125-20190517-v5.4.hdf')
ice17 = nc17.variables['ASI Ice Concentration'][:]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30,20))
ax6 = plt.subplot(2,3,6,projection=ccrs.Mercator(min_latitude=77,max_latitude=81))
mm = ax6.contour(lons,lats,ice17,vmin=0,vmax=100,
                   transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap='BuPu',zorder=1)
plt.title('May 17th stations: δ15N vaules',size='x-large')
ax6.set_extent([-10,10,77,81])
ax6.coastlines()
```

Expected results are a clean contour line, with no gap, but instead a gap appears as shown.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this, the issue was that my longitudinal values jumped from 0 to 360 at longitude zero. By subtracting 360 from all longitude values > 180 the problem was solved, and the plot looks appropriate now.